# Apple push Notification on sandbox

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've been working on apple push notification. The code works fine for the first time and sends the notification to the device. But it doesn't send for the second time after some interval of first time notification. I don't know why is that. I'm closing the connection.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ios.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '1234567881');

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp) {
    $response['message'] = "Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL;
    return $response;
}
$response['error'] = false;
$response['message'] = 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;


// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => 'this is from test',
    'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', 'de785a64fd2ee4cc4e0adf067856528c846c0f1e4fe30f88694e59f808f9d3ba') . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;


fclose($fp);

die;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message

Comment: No error message but some resourse id

Comment: I faced same problem because of device token. After some time device token get changed and device stopped receiving notification. I do not know why. You should check device token and try same code. It should work.

Comment: Well, already checked the device token. The token is correct. I'm afraid it's  connection closing issue. Connection isn't being closed correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I am using exactly the some code and it's work perfectly.
Maybe try to remove the "die" at the end.